# Azure custom question and answering service "create bot" button doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

Created a Bot using azure's own "create a bot" button but the Bot returns an error.

These are my steps: created a "custom and answer" service on azure language. deployed it and then clicked on "Create a Bot". This then took me to another page to create other services to create the bot. Did that but the BOT doesn't work. I get the below error:

> The bot encountered an error or bug.
>
> Bot said: To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.
> Bot said: To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to go to your Language service in azure then click on Keys and Endpoint on navbar. There you should have 2 keys, copy one of them. Paste this key into MicrosoftAppId field when the "Create a Bot" button takes you to a wizard to create a web app.

if you have already created your web app and bot without this key then go to your web app service and then go to configuration tab. There change MicrosoftAppId field to your language service key.